# Prompt the errors form forms using flat structure code

Tags: django

I prompt the users error in form with triple nested code as:

```
{% for field in form  %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        {% for error in field.errors  %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger"> {{ field.label }}: {{ error }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Could such a multiple nested structure be achieved in a straightforward way?

Comment: I would say that `if` is unnecessary,  because if the list is empty,  you won't do any iterations inside loop anyway.

Comment: I did not follow your idea. o(╥﹏╥)o @AlexandrTatarinov